# Creating a data frame from looping through a list of data frames in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have a large data set that is organized as a list of 1044 data frames. Each data frame is a profile that holds the same data for a different station and time. I am trying to create a data frame that holds the output of my function `fitsObs`, but my current code only goes through a single data frame. Any ideas?

```
    i=1
start=1
for(i in 1:1044){
  station1 <- surveyCTD$stations[[i]]
  df1 <- surveyCTD$data[[i]]
  date1 <- surveyCTD$dates[[i]]

  fitObs <- fitTp2(-df1$depth, df1$temp)

  if(start==1){
    start=0
    dfout <- data.frame(
      date=date1
      ,station=station1
    )
    names(fitObs) <- paste0(names(fitObs),"o")
    dfout<-cbind(dfout, df1$temp, df1$depth)
    dfout <- cbind(dfout, fitObs)

  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide an example of your list. Also have a look at `do.call` and `lapply`.

Answer (score 0):

From a first look I would try two ways to debug it. First print out the head of a DF to understand the behavior of your loop, then check the range of your variable dfout, it looks like the variable is local to your loop.

Moreover your i variable out of the loop does not change anything in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a reproducible example of my best guess as to what you are asking. I also assume that you are able to adjust the concepts in this general example to suit your own problem. It's easier if you provide an example of your list in future.

First we create some reproducible data

```
a <- c(10,20,30,40)
b <- c(5,10,15,20)
c <- c(20,25,30,35)
df1 <- data.frame(x=a+1,y=b+1,z=c+1)
df2 <- data.frame(x=a,y=b,z=c)
ls1 <- list(df1,df2)
```

Which looks like this

```
print(ls1)
[[1]]
   x  y  z
1 11  6 21
2 21 11 26
3 31 16 31
4 41 21 36

[[2]]
   x  y  z
1 10  5 20
2 20 10 25
3 30 15 30
4 40 20 35
```

So we now have two dataframes within a single list. The following code should then work to go through the columns within each dataframe of the list and apply the mean() function to the data in the column. You change this to row by selecting '1' rather than '2'.

```
df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(ls1, function(x) apply(x,2,mean)))
as.data.frame(df)
print(df)
   x   y   z
1 26 13.5 28.5
2 25 12.5 27.5
```

You should be able to replace mean() with whatever function you have written for your data. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Consider building a generalized function to be called withi `Map` (wrapper to `mapply`, the **m**ultiple, elementwise iterator member of **apply** family) to build a list of data frames each with your *fitObs* output. And pass all equal length objects into the `data.frame()` constructor.

Then outside the loop, run `do.call` for a final, single appended dataframe of all 1,044 smaller dataframes (assuming each maintains exact same and number of columns):

```
# GENERALIZED FUNCTION
add_fit_obs <- function(dt, st, df) {

   fitObs <- fitTp2(-df$depth, df$temp)
   names(fitObs) <- paste0(names(fitObs),"o")

   tmp <- data.frame(
       date = dt,
       station = st,
       depth = df1$depth,
       temp = df1$temp,
       fitObs      
    )

   return(tmp)
}

# LIST OF DATA FRAMES
df_list <- Map(add_fit_obs, surveyCTD$stations, surveyCTD$dates, surveyCTD$data) 
# EQUIVALENTLY:
# df_list <- mapply(add_fit_obs, surveyCTD$stations, surveyCTD$dates, surveyCTD$data, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)

# SINGLE DATAFRAME
master_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```